# Swift NSOSStatusErrorDomain when trying to call a number

Tags: swift

I have this code in my Swift:

```
       Text(item.telephone)
        .onTapGesture {
              guard let number = URL(string: "tel://" + item.telephone) else { return }
              UIApplication.shared.open(number)
         }
```

And I want it to call the number its showing. I tried with +994 and without, but in either cases I was given

```
 Failed to open URL tel://0501234556: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSLine=247, _LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient openURL:options:completionHandler:]}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: You seem to be using a simulator to open the `tel://` which will produce the error you got. So check if it's possible to open the url with `canOpen()` before executing `open()`.

```
Text(item.telephone)
    .onTapGesture {
        guard let number = URL(string: "tel://" + item.telephone) else { return }
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(number) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(number)
        } else {
            print("Can't open url on this device")
        }
}
```

Note: Make sure the `item.telephone` the parameter doesn't contain anything else other than the number.

Comment: I tried it, alas the same result. Can it be because I'm running it on a simulator and not on an iphone?

Comment: That could be it. Use the check as I have given in my answer. You need a real device.